# Web server does not allow public connections

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, webserver, ddns

I cannot access a local web server in a VM for testing and I don't understand why. SSH and VNC work fine. The server is a Virtualbox bitnami machine with a bridged connection running on a laptop.

This is the IP configuration:

Modem/router address: 192.168.1.1
Laptop: 192.168.1.86
VM: 192.168.1.89

- The modem/router is connected to the Internet, and I have a a DDNS domain on noip.com fully working.
- I can both ping the modem from my public IP and my public domain from outside the LAN.
- I have configured the following ports on the modem/router:
  `SSH     192.168.1.89   TCP     TCP:22  TCP:22  active`
  `HTTP    192.168.1.89   TCP     TCP:80  TCP:80  active`
  `VNC     192.168.1.86   TCP     5900    5900    active`
- Inside the LAN I can access the server both from the laptop and from other devices.
- Outside the LAN using the DDNS address, I can access the laptop with VNC and the VM with SSH

So basically, everything works fine except HTTP.

Comment: It is a custom Bitnami vbox. I found it's running Apache + mysql.

bitnami@ubuntu:~/apps/magento$ sudo /etc/init.d/bitnami status
varnish already running
php-fpm already running
apache already running
mysql already running
Memcached already running


Hope this is good enough. if not ask me what information do you need:

Comment: You say **`I cannot access the local webserver in my home for testing`**, and then you say **`From inside the lan, I can access the server both from the laptop and from other devices`**. Are both these statements referring to the web site on the VM using TCP port 80? If so, then those statements sound contradicting unless your home and lan are different locations perhaps, to me either it does or it does not allow access on the same subnet locally. You might check the NIC config on the host the VM is running on isn't blocking or routing the traffic to the VM or something along those lines,,,

Comment: check on your bitnami vm where it listens and if a firewall is setup. but it is probably that you have forward port 80 on your router and you should select another port as they tend to have a WebGUI and by default deny access from WAN. So forward port eg 8080 on your router to your .89 port 80.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT yes. my home is in my lan, and I can access the vm from inside the lan, but not from outside home. how do i check the NIC config?

Comment: @Zina tried opening the ports, nothing happened.

also, I tried this commands to understand which port is open, but I cannot understand which are in use. I uploaded the results here: http://pastebin.com/qecf4sYN

Comment: seems your bitnami apache listens on port 81, make a plain `netstat -anutp' so we can see what listen where. and use the found port for forwarding (and again I would not use 80 on your public IP for forwarding). you can also check from you computer to bitnami with nmap which port are shown as open.

Comment: @Zina this is the netstat -anutp: http://pastebin.com/RFuKuRNY. I have tried to change 80 to 81 but still no progress

Comment: @Zina could it be an interference between the win10 host ports and the vm guest? because if I run xampp on win10, with the port mapping to the windows ip, the default xampp webpage is reachable

Comment: Could you try to forward port 8081 on your router to port 8081 of your host PC (.86) and add a NATed vNIC to your VM and then in VirtualBox forward port 8081 to port 80 and the NATed IP of your VM? This worked for me on OSX 10.11.5 and VirtualBox Version 5.0.24 r108355 (I don't have a Windows machine and my HUAWEI F2000 router does not list devices with bridged vNICs - so I can't test it).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your ISP is blocking the connection from outside your network.

Many ISPs block common service ports (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, SMTP, etc.) to prevent customers from running hosted services out of their homes unless they subscribe to "Business Class" or some higher tier service for a higher price.

Blocking those specific ports effectively stops people from running a business on a residential service plan.

Check with your ISP to see if this is what they're doing.

Also check to see if you're running a firewall inside the VM.  Port 80/443 may need to be opened up.  Since you can connect fine via SSH, I suspect you've probably already considered that, however.

Answer (score 0):

From your posts in the comments and the output of sudo lsof -i is visible that there is varnishd running on the machine which is HTTP accelerator daemon.
 
"The varnishd daemon accepts HTTP requests from clients, passes them on to a backend server and caches the returned documents to better satisfy future requests for the same document."
There is probably something wrong with it's configuration. Have a look at this:
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/reference/varnishd.html